# JAX: time to jit a function grows superlinear with memory accessed by function

Tags: python, jax

Here is a simple example, which numerically integrates the product of two Gaussian pdfs. One of the Gaussians is fixed, with mean always at 0. The other Gaussian varies in its mean:

```py
import time

import jax.numpy as np
from jax import jit
from jax.scipy.stats.norm import pdf

# set up evaluation points for numerical integration
integr_resolution = 6400
lower_bound = -100
upper_bound = 100
integr_grid = np.linspace(lower_bound, upper_bound, integr_resolution)
proba = pdf(integr_grid)
integration_weight = (upper_bound - lower_bound) / integr_resolution


# integrate with new mean
def integrate(mu_new):
    x_new = integr_grid - mu_new

    proba_new = pdf(x_new)
    total_proba = sum(proba * proba_new * integration_weight)

    return total_proba


print('starting jit')
start = time.perf_counter()
integrate = jit(integrate)
integrate(1)
stop = time.perf_counter()
print('took: ', stop - start)
```

The function looks seemingly simple, but it doesn't scale at all. The following list contains pairs of (value for integr_resolution, time it took to run the code):

- 100 | 0.107s
- 200 | 0.23s
- 400 | 0.537s
- 800 | 1.52s
- 1600 | 5.2s
- 3200 | 19s
- 6400 | 134s

For reference, the unjitted function, applied to `integr_resolution=6400` takes 0.02s.

I thought that this might be related to the fact that the function is accessing a global variable. But moving the code to set up the integration points inside of the function has no notable influence on the timing. The following code takes 5.36s to run. It corresponds to the table entry with 1600 which previously took 5.2s:

```py
# integrate with new mean
def integrate(mu_new):
    # set up evaluation points for numerical integration
    integr_resolution = 1600
    lower_bound = -100
    upper_bound = 100
    integr_grid = np.linspace(lower_bound, upper_bound, integr_resolution)
    proba = pdf(integr_grid)
    integration_weight = (upper_bound - lower_bound) / integr_resolution

    x_new = integr_grid - mu_new

    proba_new = pdf(x_new)
    total_proba = sum(proba * proba_new * integration_weight)

    return total_proba
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also answered this at https://github.com/google/jax/issues/1776, but adding the answer here too.

It's because the code uses `sum` where it should use `np.sum`.

`sum` is a Python built-in that extracts each element of a sequence and sums them one by one using the `+` operator. This has the effect of building a large, unrolled chain of adds which XLA takes a long time to compile.

If you use `np.sum`, then JAX builds a single XLA reduction operator, which is much faster to compile.

And just to show how I figured this out: I used `jax.make_jaxpr`, which dumps JAX's internal trace representation of a function. Here, it shows:

```
In [3]: import jax

In [4]: jax.make_jaxpr(integrate)(1)
Out[4]:
{ lambda b c ;  ; a.
  let d = convert_element_type[ new_dtype=float32
                                old_dtype=int32 ] a
      e = sub c d
      f = sub e 0.0
      g = pow f 2.0
      h = div g 1.0
      i = add 1.8378770351409912 h
      j = neg i
      k = div j 2.0
      l = exp k
      m = mul b l
      n = mul m 2.0
      o = slice[ start_indices=(0,)
                 limit_indices=(1,)
                 strides=(1,)
                 operand_shape=(100,) ] n
      p = reshape[ new_sizes=()
                   dimensions=None
                   old_sizes=(1,) ] o
      q = add p 0.0
      r = slice[ start_indices=(1,)
                 limit_indices=(2,)
                 strides=(1,)
                 operand_shape=(100,) ] n
      s = reshape[ new_sizes=()
                   dimensions=None
                   old_sizes=(1,) ] r
      t = add q s
      u = slice[ start_indices=(2,)
                 limit_indices=(3,)
                 strides=(1,)
                 operand_shape=(100,) ] n
      v = reshape[ new_sizes=()
                   dimensions=None
                   old_sizes=(1,) ] u
      w = add t v
      x = slice[ start_indices=(3,)
                 limit_indices=(4,)
                 strides=(1,)
                 operand_shape=(100,) ] n
      y = reshape[ new_sizes=()
                   dimensions=None
                   old_sizes=(1,) ] x
      z = add w y
... similarly ...
```

and it's then obvious why this is slow: the program is very big.

Contrast the `np.sum` version:

```
In [5]: def integrate(mu_new):
   ...:     x_new = integr_grid - mu_new
   ...:
   ...:     proba_new = pdf(x_new)
   ...:     total_proba = np.sum(proba * proba_new * integration_weight)
   ...:
   ...:     return total_proba
   ...:

In [6]: jax.make_jaxpr(integrate)(1)
Out[6]:
{ lambda b c ;  ; a.
  let d = convert_element_type[ new_dtype=float32
                                old_dtype=int32 ] a
      e = sub c d
      f = sub e 0.0
      g = pow f 2.0
      h = div g 1.0
      i = add 1.8378770351409912 h
      j = neg i
      k = div j 2.0
      l = exp k
      m = mul b l
      n = mul m 2.0
      o = reduce_sum[ axes=(0,)
                      input_shape=(100,) ] n
  in [o] }
```

Hope that helps!